# litecoin minerd errors

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration

i have run through [this](http://cryptocur.com/litecoin/litecoin-mining/) tutorial but when i run:

```
c:\ltcminer\minerd.exe -a scrypt -r 1 -t 4 -s 6 -o http://127.0.0.1:9332 -O pete345234.2:1
```

i get errors:

```
json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

do i need to use the litecoinpool.org url instead of `127.0.0.1`? also does the password matter for minerd.exe

i'm a bit stuck...

**edit 1**

i changed the command to this:

```
c:\ltcminer\minerd.exe -a scrypt -r 1 -t 4 -s 6 -o us2.litecoinpool.org:9332 -O pete345234.2:1
```

but still the response is the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minerd was too old a version:

```
minerd --version
cpuminer 2.2.2
```

i downloaded cpuminer 2.3.2 and now everything is sweet. the command to get minerd working is:

```
minerd.exe -a scrypt -r1 -t4 -s6 -o stratum+tcp://us2.litecoinpool.org:3333 -O pete345234.2:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use your pool adress instead of yours.
Password usually doesn't matter, however you can set it on pool website.

This tutorial shows creating your own pool, but since this question also shows that you are a begginer, start by mining by someone else.

Comment: it doesn't work. any more ideas?